# Kernel connection broken in VS Code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I'm working with Jupyter Notebooks on VS Code and everytime I try to run all my code it keeps showing this error:
"Error: Direct kernel connection broken"
I've tried everything to make it work properly but it won't. I don't know if this is a problem with the kernel itself, with python installation or my virtual env (which is using python 3.6.12 and some machine learning oriented packages such as tensorflow, keras etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Switch kernel from `.venv` to default then switch it back again.